# How can I use the ItemCreated event to update the text of a label control contained in a formview?

Tags: vb.net, formview, replace, databound

How can I replace the text of a label control contained in a formview?

I've tried to use the code below:

```
Protected Sub FormViewNews_DataBound(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FormViewNews.DataBound
    Dim pagerRow As FormViewRow = FormViewNews.BottomPagerRow

    Dim Active As Label = CType(pagerRow.Cells(2).FindControl("OFMLabel"), Label)

    If Active = "False" Then
        Active = "Public"
    Else
        Active = "Private"
    End If
End Sub
```

But then I've got this error message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

i.e. I have a label named 'OFMLabel', and its valued 'TRUE'. Then, if TRUE, I want to change its text become 'PRIVATE', and if FALSE, become 'PUBLIC'.

Anyone can help me, please?

Thanks.

This problem solved with the code below:

**SOLVED**

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "False" Then
            e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Public"
        Else
            e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Private"
        End If
    End If
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved using the code below:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    If e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "False" Then
        e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Public"
    Else
        e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Private"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to say what you want to change.
You cant change a label to private, you want the text to say private right?

```
If Active.text = "False" Then
Active.text = "Public"
```

maybe that?
You want to check on something. dont forget to say WHAT you want to check.
in this case its the text of your label right?
Or did I get it all wrong?

Hope this could help you in any way.

Comment: That's not what I mean. What I want is, replace the text in gridview from server-side code. So, if I have a label (on gridview) named "Active", and it valued "TRUE", then I want to replace that "TRUE" text become "ACTIVE". If it valued "FALSE", then I want to replace that text become "NON-ACTIVE"...

Comment: Then what about:

`If Active = "False" Then
Active.text = "YourValue"
Else
Active.text = "YourOtherValue"
End If`

You still need to say you want to alter the text of that label.
Just changing a label in general wont alter the text.

Comment: I've solved the problem with the code edited above. Thanks anw =)